# Laravel routes not working correctly on digital ocean LAMP droplet

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess

I am able to access my Laravel site with `mysite.com/` routing correctly with / retrieving the welcome view.

I am able to access files in my public directory such as
`mysite.com/img/test.jpg`

But when I try to access any other routes, such as `mysite.com/login`.

I get the following error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /contact was not found on this server.

It looks like the application is trying to access another route that is not hitting `index.php` to generate the view accordingly.

I am using the default `.htaccess` file that Laravel comes with.

My apache conf file points to my public directory.

Anyone run into a similar issue before?

Comment: Have you defined the route in `/routes/web.php` ? `Route::get('/login',callback);`or if you are using built-in authentication: `Auth::routes();` added in your boot or register method of the serviceprovider

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue and I did everything that was mentioned in different articles but issue was still there

1. enable rewrite mode using `sudo a2ensite rewrite`
2. update conf file located at /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.conf

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/html/project/public>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
   </Directory>
   ```
3. then restarted server using `sudo service apache2 restart`

After doing all above steps issue was still there then I changed apache2.conf file and everything was working fine.

In

```
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

change just 3rd line as shown below

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None   //change this line to AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

After that I did not have to add `../index.php/...` in the urls

Comment: For step number 1, it is `sudo a2enmod rewrite` instead of  `a2ensite`.

Please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to enable mod rewrite

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Restart Apache.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Follow the tutorial on the link below

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04